# How do I make my Delphi 5 app display password "blobs"?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-5

Pretty simple one, but I can't find the answer.

I'm building an app in Delphi 5 Enterprise, and want my app to use the new bold black dot in a password field instead of an asterisk.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to all the above attempts, and all that contributed, but I had to join all the relevant parts together to get to a whole solution.

Thanks to Sinan Ünür for pointing out the ES_PASSWORD flag, which is used by default in Delphi, but only if PasswordChar is <> #0 (NUL).

This means that when you set PasswordChar to something, it sets the ES_PASSWORD flag, and then calls `SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Ord(FPasswordChar), 0);` (thanks to  Stijn Sanders for pointing me towards the StdCtrls source).

If I create a subclass and bypass the line sending the EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR field, I **still** get only stars.

What I was forgetting to do was enable themes (which in my ancient version of Delphi requires a resource file compiling in). Hey presto, it works; Blobs abound!

So, in summary:

1. Define the ES_PASSWORD constant if you don't already have it.

   ```
   const
     ES_PASSWORD = 32;
   ```
2. Create a TEdit subclass and override [`CreateParams`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.CreateParams) to include ES_PASSWORD in the window style.

   ```
   procedure TPasswordEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
   begin
     inherited;
     Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_PASSWORD;
   end;
   ```
3. Enable themes for your program.

And do *not* set the PasswordChar property. Done!

Answer (score 10):

See [PasswordBox: A Better Way to Enter Passwords](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/passwordbox.aspx):

> Getting the black dots to show up based on the visual style was insanely simple!

```
    private const int ES_PASSWORD = 0x0020;
    ...

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        ...

        cp.Style |= ES_PASSWORD;
        ...

        return cp;
    }
```

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Thank you. I don't know any Delphi but it ought to be fairly straightforward to translate.

Comment: If I have a quick look in unit StdCtrls, I notice that TCustomEdit has a virtual CreateParams to override. (It even may already set the ES_PASSWORD flag when FPasswordChar<>#0

Comment: I've overridden CreateParams and passed ES_PASSWORD (32 in decimal?) and I still get "*" instead of the new password "blob".

Comment: @Drarok Note that the code above is not setting `cp.Style` to `0x0020`. It is setting `cp.Style = cp.Style | 0x0020` where `|` is bitwise `or`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure it uses the standard UI font. The CharMap code is U+25CF

I dunno if this will work, but you might be able to copy this.

●

Comment: The problem is that in versions prior to Delphi 2009, the PasswordChar property is of type AnsiChar, which cannot hold that character. Delphi 2009 and later accept a Unicode character for that property, but according to Bruce's answer, you don't need to set the character manually because the control already shows the right character.

Answer (score 2):

According to [KB 956609](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/956609), the dot character is Unicode 0x25cf. It isn't tied to a particular font, but the linked page specifically mentioned that IE uses the Tahoma font.

Answer (score 2):

Up to Delphi 2007, using `"*"` for your password character would show as `"*"`.  Starting with Delphi 2009, this [shows properly](http://glooscapsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/delphi-2009-passwordchar.html).

Answer (score 1):

The bold black dot in password fields is Unicode character U+25CF ("BLACK CIRCLE"). Most common fonts feature this character.